# When can I assume that the antiderivative contains $(0,0)$

Tags: integration

I know that
$$\int_{0}^{x} {f'(t)dt}=f(x)+C$$
But I also know that this equation represents the area under $f'(x)$ between $0$ and $x$.

Could I reason that at $x=0$, that $f(x)=0$ since the area under $f'(x)$ between $0$ and $0$ is going to be $0$ and therefore the integral contains the point $(0,0)$, enabling me to find $C$?

Comment: You are mixing up definite integral and indefinite integral (aka antiderivative). $\int_{0}^{x} {f'(t)dt}=f(x) - f(0)$.

Comment: No, $\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt\ne f(x)+C$. That "$+C$" happens with an _indefinite_ integral; this is a _definite_ integral, which has a single value. (In fact the integral is $f(x)-f(0)$, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus...)

Comment: But when can I assume the antiderivative contains the point $(0,0)$ or otherwise allow me to find $C$

Comment: The derivative of $x(x+2)$ is $2x+2$.  The derivative of $(x+1)^2$ is also  $2x+2$.  So what is *the* antiderivative of $2x+2$?

Comment: Expanding @MartinR's comment $\int_{0}^{x} {f'(t)dt}=(f(t)+C)\big |_0^x = (f(x)+C)-(f(0)+C) = f(x)-f(0)$.  You seem to want use $C=-f(0)$, which it can be but does not have to be

Comment: Saying an antiderivative of $e^x$ is $e^{x}-1$ would not be wrong, but it is more common to choose $e^x$ as the usual antiderivative

Comment: Okay, I think what happened is I combined the two fundamental theorems of calculus in my head. So that like $\int {f(x)dx}=\int_{0}^{x} {f(x)dx}=F(x)-F(0)$

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, since this is a definite integral by FTC we have:
$$\int_0^xf'(X)dX=f(x)-f(0)$$
evaluating the integral at $x=0$ just gives $0=0$.

So no, you cannot determine anything about the function from this general statement